# SIGABRT error with segue.destination in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a leaderboard but I am getting a SIGABRT error in the line below (I commented above the line that is causing the error). My app crashes as soon as I press the done button, which is supposed to segue to leaderboardVC (which is a table view)

```
var yourScore = 0
class secondVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//SIGABRT error
    let secondVC = segue.destination as! leaderboardVC
    secondVC.tempNumber = yourScore
    secondVC.tempName = nameTF.text ?? "Player"
    secondVC.organise()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scoreLabel.text = "Your score is: \(yourScore)"    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use segue identifier  to track the problem

```
if segue.identifier == "name" { 
  if let secondVC = segue.destination as? leaderboardVC {
     print("ok")
  }
  else {
     print(segue.destination)
  }
}
```

A common issue is you missed to set class name in IB

Answer (score 0):

There is no segue to the controller leaderboardVC. And the crash occurs as you are force wrapping the destination of segue in prepare method. Please check if the segue exists.

And always do apply the optional chaining to prevent the crashes as:

```
if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? leaderboardVC {
 print("ok")
}
```

You can debug the issue by printing the value of segue.destination.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few ways you can do this:

1.) Rightclick on the done button and remove dublicates / unused connections.

2.) Click on the eventlist of the secondary viewcontroller. (Find view - rightclick on the yellow circle on top of the controller - find unused / irrelevant connections and remove them!

3.) Add a breakpoint to check where the error occures. And edit your thread, where the error is

4.) Doublecheck the identifier for the segue. Make sure you entered exaclty like it’s written.

I’m 99% sure you screwed something up with the connections, either on viewcontroller 1 or 2. So double check this!

If this dosen’t work. Paste your error and i’ll help you out. Good luck.